# objC checking empty string, isEqualToString:@"" vs length

Tags: objective-c, syntax, compare, string

I have a string

```
NSString hi;
```

and I don't know what values will get initialized to it. Could be nil, could be empty string, could be anything.

Are there any advantages to using

```
if (![hi length])
```

vs

```
if (![hi isEqualToString:@""])
```

It seems like both cases return the same values for empty string, nil, and any other type of string. I would guess length is better because it's more efficient. It just returns a variable, where as isEqualToString has to do a comparison.

Comment: By the way, your logic is flawed. `![hi length]` does something similar to `[hi isEqualToString:@""]`, and **not** `![hi isEqualToString:@""]`.

Comment: you probably didn't intend this, but your statements are opposite. ![hi length] is true when hi is nil or empty and ![hi isEqualToString:@""] is true when hi != "". Negative logic is generally more confusing...

Comment: @pdriegen I just told this. Also, `NSString hi;` won't compile.

Comment: @H2CO3 yeah, I saw after posting..

Comment: thanks, i didn't think this question through. [hi length] is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They don't do the same thing.

`[hi length]` will return 0 for nil or an empty string and nonzero for any other string.

`[hi isEqualToString:@""]` will return 1 when `hi` is an empty string and 0 when `hi` is nil or any non-empty string.

In other words, the only value of `hi` for which the two lines of code give the same result is `nil`.

You probably wanted the behavior of option #1 (treating either nil or an empty string as "blank" and any other value as "not blank"), so that would be the one to use.

Comment: thanks, i didn't think this question through. [hi length] is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there any advantages to using `if (![hi length])`

Yes. It can check for an empty string **and** for a `nil` at the same time. You can't do this with `isEqualToString:`, since if the string is `nil`, then any message sent to it will return zero, so it won't appear to be equal to the empty string, hence requiring another check.

By the way, for clarity, you should consider using `if (hi.length != 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following

```
if (hi && ![hi isEqualToString:@""]) {

}
```

`![hi isEqualToString:@""]` alone will get you a true if `hi` is `nil`.

Comment: I would not do it. `hi.length != 0` is more concise, advising someone not using it is bad practice.

Comment: I disagree. Generally, it's definitely not bad practise to check if the object has actually been initialised. Maybe he changes the code to  `![hi isEqualToString:@"some string"]` later, and a nil value would still not be what he is looking for. But yes, in this case `hi.length != 0` would be enough.

Comment: @userXXX without context, it's kind of pointless to debate about this, it's not a bad idea to check if an object was initialized, but it seems to me that OP just looks for a way for checking for a zero-length string as easily as possible - that's why I suggested he checks the length. Of course it wouldn't be the case anymore if the string was passed to a method that expects a non-nil string, but it doesn't appear to be the case this time.

Comment: I think either option is fine, in future you can both answer with both options or link back here.